# How to integrate USPS First Class Mail International API to print label into our web application

Tags: usps

I want to integrate the USPS First Class Mail International API into our web application to print labels. I have all the necessary credentials like USERID and PASSWORD, and the test link.

I have tried to integrate it into our application, but it gives me an API authorization error like this:

```
<Error>
<Number>80040b1a</Number>
<Description>API Authorization failure. FirstClassMailIntl is not a valid API name for this protocol.</Description>
<Source>UspsCom::DoAuth</Source>
</Error>
```

Comment: You got solution? I feel USPS documentation is probably all wrong, tried everything doesn't work

Comment: you need to call then and verify the credentials or email them here:uspstechsupport@esecurecare.net